# Red squiggles not showing even when enabled. (C/C++ extension)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Till yesterday, they are working properly and detecting every syntex error, but today when I started working again I found that there is no highlighting(ERROR_SQUIGGLES) showing even if the code is not written with the correct syntex.

Even, I also tried,

```
 C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
```

in settings.json, but I'm still not getting any squiggly lines for errors.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTIIJ.png)

Here it is supposed to show the error(RED Line below the code), but it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

**You should install the official [*Java extension pack*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).**

[image]